# Does `table` round numeric values?

Tags: r

I have 120 vectors in a matrix `points` (120 x 2). I calculate their squared norms:

```
norms2 <- apply(points, 1L, crossprod)
```

I tabulate these squared norms:

```
> table(norms2)
norms2
0.410691055416468  1.62481505182984  2.37518494817016  3.58930894458353 
               30                30                30                30
```

One sees that the squared norms take four possible values, 30 vectors for each value.

I extract the vectors which have the smallest squared norm:

```
> points[norms2 == min(norms2), ]
            [,1]       [,2]
[1,]  0.06698726 -0.6373412
[2,]  0.06698726  0.6373412
[3,] -0.06698726 -0.6373412
[4,] -0.06698726  0.6373412
```

Why do I get four vectors only, and not 30?

If I extract with an approximate equality, I get 30 vectors:

```
> dim(points[abs(norms2 - min(norms2)) < 0.001, ])
[1] 30  2
```

So what is the explanation? Does `table` round the values?

Comment: Would you mind adding the data as well? That said, can't this be linked to the machine error?

Comment: in support of @GregorThomas: `as.numeric(as.character(pi)) == pi` is FALSE (!)

Comment: I cannot reproduce this. `points <- t(replicate(2, runif(2)));points <- matrix(rep(points, 60), ncol = 2)` gives a table of 4 names with all values 30. Then, `dim(points[norms2 == min(norms2), ])` is `[1] 30  2`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, `table` can round numeric input.

`table()` calls `factor()` which calls `as.character()`, and `as.character()` does some rounding:

```
x = sqrt(2)
print(x, digits = 22)
# [1] 1.414213562373095145475
as.character(x)
# [1] "1.4142135623731"
```

Here's a reproducible example:

```
x = c(pi, pi + 1e-15)

x == pi
# [1]  TRUE FALSE

as.character(x)
# [1] "3.14159265358979" "3.14159265358979"

table(x)
# x
# 3.14159265358979 
#                2
```